# Center ImageView dynamically in TableLayout

Tags: android, center, tablerow, dynamically-generated, android-tablelayout

I'm making an app where I dynamically make tablerows. Each tablerow includes 3 ImageViews and one TextView, with textview there's not any problem, I simyply use textview.setGravity(Gravity.Center_Vertical), but there's a problem with ImageViews. How to center them (Vertically and Horizontally) ?

Here's the picture wchich shows what I want to achieve: [image]

here's the class wchich adss everything to TableLayout:

```
public class Obiekt {
    int moje;
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
    ImageView sett = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
    ImageView rin = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);

    public Obiekt(int obraz, int obraz2, int obraz3, int dzwiek, String tekst) {
        moje = sound.load(MainActivity.this, dzwiek, 1);
        iv.setImageResource(obraz);
        //iv.setLayoutParams(rowparams);
        tr.addView(iv);
        // TEXTVIEW settings
        TextView tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        tv.setText(tekst);
        tv.setTypeface(tf);
        tv.setTextSize(rozmiar);
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        tr.addView(tv);
        // ImageView RIGHT
        sett.setImageResource(obraz2);
        tr.addView(sett);
        // ImageView RING
        rin.setImageResource(obraz3);
        tr.addView(rin);
        //tr.setLayoutParams(rowparams1);
        tl.addView(tr);
        View wiew = new View(MainActivity.this);
        wiew.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.divide);
        tl.addView(wiew);
        tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                play();
            }
        });
    }

    public void hide() {
        tr.setVisibility(10);
    }

    public void size() {
        iv.getLayoutParams().height=rozmiar;
        iv.getLayoutParams().width=rozmiar;
        sett.getLayoutParams().width=rozmiar;
        sett.getLayoutParams().height=rozmiar;
        rin.getLayoutParams().height=rozmiar;
        rin.getLayoutParams().width=rozmiar;
    }

    public void play() {
        sound.play(moje, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you're trying to achieve.  Please provide a drawing/screenshot.

Comment: Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618331/how-to-set-gravity-or-margins-of-imageview-using-code

Answer (score 1):

Set your imageviews "SCALE TYPE" to FitXY like for example your imageview is imageView than
imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
ImageView imgView=new ImageView(this);
imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourimage);
imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

Comment: Everything is in initial question now

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the `ImageView` inside a `RelativeLayout`?

Set the `RelativeLayout` to have `LayoutParams` that match the space you want to draw within (the full size of the cell), and then when adding the `ImageView` to the `RelativeLayout`, add it with `RelativeLayout.center_in_parent`